# When testing react project npm test works but jest doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I have used create-react-app to create a new react app and have added a couple of simple components and tests.  When running the tests using 'npm test' they run fine.  When running with jest I get 'Unexpected token' when using the imported component within the test.  For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<App />);
});
```

The usage of App within the test gives the error, but only when running jest.

Comment: what do you running with jest? create-react-app uses jest when you run `npm test`

Comment: Just playing around mostly.  trying to figure out the difference.  It looks like create-react-app creates something in package.json called 'react-scripts test --env=jsdom'.  I guess this uses jest underneath?  I'd like more control as it runs with the watcher and I don't always want to do that.  I'd also like coverage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unexpected token` error is likely to be because you haven't installed `babel-jest` and haven't add the `transform` key to the `jest.json`.  I expect createReactApp`is doing something to hide this from you.  If you want to use non-createReactApp commands (like`jest`) then i'd '[eject](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject)' the app (which can not be undone) so that you can see all configs etc.

or you could add your own jest.json, but i feel this might get confusing to have 2 ways of running tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over this, I would recommend bypassing what comes out of the box with `create-react-app`.

You can add a `test` entry in your `package.json` that will essentially use `jest`, but allow you to pass a config file.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest --config jest.conf.js",
    ...
  },
```

Then in your `jest.conf.js`, you can add variables to be used in your tests. The `collectCoverage` and `coverageDirectory` attributes are for code coverage.

```
{
  "globals":{
    "__DEV__": true,
    "API_BASE_URL": "http://api",
    "SOME_VAR": "whatever"
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react/",
      "node_modules/enzyme/"
    ]
  },
  "collectCoverage": "true",
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage"
}
```

Then when running `npm run test`, it will execute the tests using `jest`, with a custom config.